django-admin: The term 'django-admin' i
django-admin: The term 'django-admin' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
PS C:\Users\Sanskar\Desktop\django>
i want to initialize django

make sure that django is installed on your system by running python -m django --version command

Also tell as exactly what command you are running to initialize django

Sounds like the $PATH has not been updated

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If you installed Django, for example through pip, it will add an executable django-admin, but it is possible this its directory is not added to the $PATH variable. You thus should look for an executable django-admin, and add the directory to the $PATH environment variable.
That being said, you don't need django-admin. In fact, django-admin is a shortcut for python -m django, so you can replace any:
django-admin …
with:
python -m django …
